# cannot marshal <type 'datetime.date'> objects

Tags: python, django, web-services, odoo, xmlrpclib

I am trying save record from django (front-end) to openerp (back-end). I am using openerp webservice using xmlrpclib. It works well with normal string and number data, but when i tried to pass date field, it throws error. `cannot marshal <type 'datetime.date'> objects`

Please help me..

Comment: It looks like it cannot be done by `xmlrpc`. You should try to pickle it or convert to string.

Comment: convert the date into string and then pass the value

Comment: Thanks to all for your support. I got solution, First I have to covert date into ISO 8601 format to pass as xmlrpc object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the `cannot marshal <type 'datetime.date'> objects` error, first convert the date into ISO 8601 format, and then pass it as an object to `xmlrpclib`.

For example:

```
    dob = form.date_of_birth
    xmlrpc_dob = dob.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

For more details you can read [the official Python documentation of `xmlrpclib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html#datetime-objects).

Comment: Actually, ISO 8601 requires dashes between year, month and day. Therefore, the strftime call becomes dob.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"). Without the dashes, Odoo 10 still doesn't like the date.

Comment: Don't use `strftime()` for this. There's a built in function [`datetime.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat).

Answer (score -1):

Aternatively you can promote `datetime.date()` to `datetime.datetime()` before sending the reply.

Comment: This has the same issue